# Disable Home Button and Have Application Full Screen with No Title (no status bar, no title) in Android Froyo

Tags: android

First off, yes I know that its not the intended behavior of the OS to disable the home button, but the application I am creating is for use on a collection of devices for use inside of a closed organization only and not public consumption. Secondly, I know that there are many similar questions and spotty answers everywhere, but no solution has been presented as of yet, so I felt it prudent (albeit somewhat self serving) to put the question out there one more time properly.

I am trying to simply create a splash screen that is also a remote network lock screen. When the device is remotely told to do so it will end the activity and the user can begin to use the device.

In the manifest this is set:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityOne" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

In the Activity:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{   
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);     
    super.onAttachedToWindow();  
}
```

Combined these stop the home button, but seem to allow the status bar to remain visible. There are several obvious reasons why I would not want the status bar visible, but most importantly once a user 'pulls down' on the status bar to see the notifications area the home button becomes usable again and the whole exercise is circumvented.

I am primarily looking for an answer to this, condoned or a hack via code. If there is not a direct modification that can be done to the code set above, I would certainly appreciate and accept an answer that properly describes (preferably with code samples) any alternative logic that achieves the same goal. The alternatives can be to modify some system files or other lower level techniques.

As a final note, please know that we have SU / Root access for all of the devices.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on onCreate method.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Using this code is the same as the manifest changes. I have already tried both ways and even both at the same time. All combinations product the same negative effect.