# How To hide status bar and disable home button at the same time?

Tags: android

I'm new here in this forum. And I have the same question with @MindWire at this following link.[The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422204/disable-home-button-and-have-application-full-screen-with-no-title-no-status-ba)

I'm developing a screen lock on Android in a project.The question is when I prevent home button, the title bar will be enabled and appear. Just like what the problem MindWire met.

I don't know how to connect with him and home someone can help me with this question.